# does anyone know of a book where it shows a sketch of the proof of the statement?

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, coproduct

I hope everyone is well.
A few days ago I was studying a bit about homological algebra and in an article they showed the following:

''Given the finitely generated $R-$modules $L_i,$ $i \in I,$ and the arbitrary $R-$modules $W_j,$ $j \in J,$ we have the following isomorphisms :

$$\prod_{i \in I} {\rm Hom} _R \left(L_i , \bigoplus_{j \in J} X_j \right) \cong\prod_{i \in I} \bigoplus_{ j \in J } {\rm hom} _R \left(L_i , X_j \right)$$

The article doesn't show details of the proof, however, it caused me doubts about the veracity of the statement, does anyone know of a book where it shows a sketch of the proof of the statement?

Something that I know is true is:
$${\rm Hom} _R \left( \bigoplus _{i \in I} L_i , \bigoplus _{j \in J} X_j \right) \cong \prod _{i \in I} {\rm Hom} _R \left(L_i , \bigoplus _{j \in J} X_j \right)$$

but i don't know if it is useful in the proof.

Comment: Did you mean $X_j$ instead of $W_j$

Comment: I have written in my own notes that $\operatorname{Hom}$ commutes with $\oplus$ in both arguments in any abelian category. I don't have any proof though and I'm not sure what the source was.